# What did Mr. Murry mean by "No such thing as a coincidence?"

Tags: a-wrinkle-in-time

In chapter 1 of *A Swiftly Tilting Planet*, an old woman (Mrs. O'Keefe) recites a spell, and some weird things happen.

> "Remember," Mr. Murry said, "your mother and I take Mrs. O'Keefe seriously."
>
> "Father," Sandy chided, "you're a pure scientist. You can't take that old woman seriously."
>
> "I take the response of the elements to her rune seriously."
>
> "Coincidence," Dennys said without much assurance.
>
> "My training in physics has taught me that there is no such thing as coincidence."

Is Dr. Murry referring to an actual concept in physics, such as whether or not the universe is deterministic, or is this actually a reference to some New Age concept like synchronicity?

Knowing the author, it does seem likely that L'Engle was thinking of synchronicity or something similar, but this seems out-of-character for Mr. Murry, who is "a pure scientist."

Is there a physics concept it would make sense for a physicist to be referring to here?

Comment: ... probably determinism, which (broadly) was a school of thought that had much more traction as nuclear physics and other modernizations were explored, not long before the author's books came out.  But that's all coming from back-of-my-head Jeopardy trivia babble, and I wouldn't know what to source for the history of a vague scientific philosophy.

Answer (score 13):

As a professional physicist, I can attest that there is no scientific principle that Dr. Murray is referring to here.

However, Dr. Murray is not, by any possible stretch, a typical scientist.  Like his children, he was part of the bizarre adventure in *A Wrinkle in Time*.

Murray knows, absolutely well, that things in the universe do not work the way most 20th century scientists believe.  This is a man who was the subject of a teleportation experiment gone totally wrong.  He ended up nowhere near the target, yet somehow in all the endless expanse of space, he found himself on a habitable planet--indeed a virtual twin of Earth, human inhabitants and all!  What would be the odds of that happening, if it were really by chance?

And when he was imprisoned on the distant planet Camazotz, three celestial beings (one a former star) descended to Earth to help two of his kids rescue him.  That does not really fit with the usual scientific cosmology of the universe.  He knows that a lot more is going on than humanity can appreciate, and things are happening for reasons, even if they are reasons we are not ready to understand.